# Writing utility like cmp for Unix to handle optional [SKIP] parameters

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, while-loop

I need to make utility like `cmp` for Unix in C.
cmp compares two files and outputs number of first char that are different.

```
cmp [-s] file1 file2 [SKIP1] [SKIP2]
```

I did everything well, but with skipping chars I've got some troubles.
`SKIP1` is used for compare `file1` after n chars and `SKIP2` is used for compare `file2` after n chars.

Part of code:

```
...
while ((fgets(filebuff,  MAXLINE, file1)) != NULL && 
       (fgets(filebuff2, MAXLINE, file2)) != NULL)
{
    ++linepos;
    same = compare_str(filebuff, filebuff2); // my function that return 0 if equal and change pos of first diff element 
    if (same != 0)
    {
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);
        printf("differ: char %i, line %i\n",charpos,linepos);
        return 1;
    }
}
fclose(file1);
fclose(file2);
return 0;
```

I don't know how to compare with beginning from SKIP1 or SKIP2.

```
while ((fgets(filebuff, MAXLINE, file1))!=NULL && (fgets(filebuff2, MAXLINE, file2)) != NULL)
```

this code reads file line by line and every both lines from every file send to function. I don't want to change my compare function. I need to send already cut string. Maybe start loop with `fgets()` from n position, but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you consider calling `fseek` ?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using `fgets()` (you should be using `fread()` instead).  One primary reason for that is that `cmp` is used to compare binary files, and the nulls that often appear in binary data really gum up the works.  You will need to modify the compare code to take a length of data for each of the buffers. Using `fseek()` is most of the rest of the answer.